# django wsgi setup with settings subfolder

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm trying differents environment settings for my project, below is my project folder structure:

```
|-app
|-project
 |-__init__.py
 |-settings
  |-__init__.p
  |-base.py
  |-dev.py
  |-prod.py
 |-urls.py
 |-wsgi.py
```

In base.py, how can i setup WSGI_APPLICATION django settings variable to point wsgi file on parent folder ?

File wsgi.py:

```
if base.STATUS == 'DEV':
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.dev')
  application = get_wsgi_application()
elif base.STATUS == 'PROD':
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.prod')
  application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
else:
  raise Exception('Settings App Error !')
```

File base.py:

```
...
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'
...
```

File dev:

```
from project.settings.base import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
DEBUG = TRUE
```

File prod.py:

```
from project.settings.base import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain']
DEBUG = FALSE
```

The error is:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'project.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by looking at the directory structure above, you have `__init__.p` under the settings. "y" is missing. It may be typo. Correct that to `__init__.py` and try again and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The differents configuration environments are ok the problem was with a library dependency:

The requirements.py file was:

> django-static

instead of:

> dj-static

The strange is the error thrown was:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

instead of:

> ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score 1):

Your WSGI file is named `wsgy.py`, but Django expects `wsgi.py`. Rename the file to `wsgi.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file in your project folder to import your project folder as a module. Just make an empty `__init__.py` file in the project directory.